# Qt DBus: trouble with struct interface from objbase.h

Tags: qt-creator, qt5, dbus

When I create a DBus interface / adaptor with `qdbusxml2cpp` on a Win 7/x86 system (Qt 5.1), I face the following problem: As soon as I include `MyAdaptor.h` (or `MyInterface.h`) somehow `objbase.h` is included (from the generated code).

A definition there `#define interface __STRUCT__` seems to cause numerous compilation errors such as here:

```
connection.interface()->isServiceRegistered // interface !!!
```

Actually everywhere, where it finds "interface", not even in my code, but also in Qt code such as

```
QDBusInterface(const QString &service, const QString &path, const QString &interface
```

In my code I have tried `#undef interface`, which solves the compilation errors (side effects so far ignored). But this ain't no solution for external code.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Can you include the code from the class you are trying to expose via DBus? It has probably to do with the way you have defined your class.